# "*/" as a data conversion operator

Tags: parsing, math, operators, expression, can-bus

I am currently reverse engineering a SQL database for in-car communications over a CAN network. Specifically, this is from the internal database of Volvo‘s VIDA diagnostics program.

There is a table dedicated to conversion functions, which convert some bits from a CAN frame into a meaningful value with some physical unit.

This has gone well for the most part, however, I found this one conversion function which I don’t understand:
`x*/32+8`

[image]

I cannot find anything online for that operator. Someone on Discord suggested this might be something related to bit stuffing, though I am not sure this applies here, as the CAN voltage levels have already been processed by the controller at this point.

I have no information about the exact values that `x` could be. However, I know from the database that this is supposed to be for the battery voltage. As this is for cars, I would assume that the equation should equal something around 12 to 13V from x being some 8-bit value.

[image]

Does anybody know what perhaps this operator could mean, if its not just a typo?

Comment: Is it possible that `x*` is a notation for "the value which needs to be converted" or something like that?  Does `x*` occur anywhere else? If there is any accompanying documentation, maybe look there too. Just guessing here.

Comment: There's zero documentation about this database that I am aware of. And no, no other functions look anything like this. Some examples would be `x*0.14`, `x&0x7fffff` or `((((x&0xff00)/256)+((x&0x0003)*256))-512)*0.25`.